# Show password button

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm developing a module and in the settings page I've inserted a `text` field to allow users to insert a key.

I thought to change this into a `password` field but I want to also create a **Show password** button or a checkbox. How could I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 9):

[Password Toggle](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_toggle) is already doing something of this sort. Code is simple and straight

Its basically a JS to be added at the right time.

```
function password_toggle_add_js_and_css() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'password_toggle');
  drupal_add_js($path . '/password_toggle.js');
  drupal_add_css($path . '/password_toggle.css');
}
```

You can borrow the module's js code for your module.

Answer (score 4):

That's the kind of functionality you'd want to implement with jquery.

If you google up "jquery show password" you'll get over a million results.

First on the list you get this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/herdiansc/dnznh/8/ 
which does the trick with a checkbox.

Do you see how you can adapt that jquery script to your module ?